# Add mulitple inline style from code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I know i can add style from code behind this way

```
imgStory1.Style.Add("display","block");
imgStory1.Style.Add("border", "none"); 
imgStory1.Style.Add("outline", "none");
imgStory1.Style.Add("height", "auto !important");
```

and so on, but I would like to do it in a much efficient way if possible. Please note I cannot do this through CSS it has to be inline styling.

Comment: I guess there is no other way of doing this in asp.net.

Comment: inline CSS is the worst thing you can do. You sould consider to use classes.

Comment: @florian have you built Emails before? Clients don't support CSS in the header

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way to write it in one line

```
imgStory1.Attributes.Add("style", "display: center;border: none; outline: none");
```

for overwriting existing

```
imgStory1.Attributes["style"] = "display: center;border: none; outline: none";
```

Comment: That makes abs sense